# Confused on understanding the cryptographic terms

Tags: cryptography

I am doing the assignment for C program where I have to use cryptography. I do have to use some of the cryptographic functions, and I do not have any idea what that functions mean to me. Some of the functions are `EVP_MD_CTX`,  `EVP_DigestUpdate()`. Can anyone tell me how to understand the use of these functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are OpenSSL's terrible APIs for computing cryptographic hashes.  See: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/EVP_DigestInit.html . Just see the examples on the page.  You have to understand that back in the 1990s, nobody had a clue about how to write a cryptographic API that was usable to a human who doesn't have a PhD in cryptography.  In general, you should never have to call such a terrible API.  Times have changed, and cryptographic APIs have hugely improved.

Comment: The `EVP_*` functions are newer. They replace the old, cobbled together API. The `EVP_*` functions offer a consistent interface regardless of the algorithm. Also see [EVP Interfaces](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP) on the OpenSSL wiki.